# Bootstrap vue select sending old value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I got this select code based on vue bootstrap:

```
<b-form-select v-model="selectedgroup" class="mb-3"  @change="searchSubGroup()">
    <option :value="null">Select a group</option>
    <option v-for="group in groupItem" :value="group.id">
        {{group.nome}}
    </option>
</b-form-select>
```

When the `searchSubGroup()` method is called by @change event, the @change event pass a old value of `selectedgroup`. Example: If i click in option with value = 1 first, the method will call `selectedgroup` as `null`, then if i click again in another option with value = 2, the method will call `selectedgroup` as 1.

```
searchSubGroup(){ 
  this.axios.get("http://chart.solutions/public/api/produto/subgroup/search/" + this.selectedgroup + "/").then(response => {
        if (response.data.erro) {
            //console.log("subgroup doesnt exist")
        }else{
            this.subGroupItem = response.data;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code for `searchSubGroup()`?

Comment: Topic updated, thanks

Comment: Hmm, I think it would be necessary to have more of the variables and methods you use, I know that you need to have an array for that component, but what do you receive from that get request? What are the values on the array you try to iterate? What is `selectedgroup`?

Comment: selectedgroup is just a data, i start like this: selectedgroup: null.
the same way as it is done in the documentation.
Seems the @change it's getting value before change the v-model

Comment: Remove the () from the @change call ;p @change="searchSubGroup"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call your `searchSubGroup` method without the parentheses. This will automatically pass the newly selected value to your method ..

```
<b-form-select v-model="selectedgroup" class="mb-3"  @change="searchSubGroup">
    <option :value="null">Select a group</option>
    <option v-for="group in groupItem" :value="group.id">
        {{group.nome}}
    </option>
</b-form-select>
```

Then in your method you should do the following ..

```
searchSubGroup(value){ 
  this.axios.get("http://chart.solutions/public/api/produto/subgroup/search/" + value + "/").then(response => {
        if (response.data.erro) {
            //console.log("subgroup doesnt exist")
        }else{
            this.subGroupItem = response.data;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: This is literally the same answer, except you're not explaining why it works. When you remove the parenthesis and capture VALUE, youre skipping over the issue, which is that v-model's @change call is getting made AFTER and thus "this.selectedgroup" was NULL when the method was called.

Comment: @Marina I have to respectfully disagree. His issue was that he was using the stored value. Instead of waiting for that value to be updated after the event by waiting for `nextTick` or some other strategy he could just use the emitted value by the event itself.

Comment: @HusamIbrahim Precisely. Because he was using the stored value (which is being updated on the second change call) the problem was occurring. If you check the docs: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-select under events you can see that the change even is fired on user input, that means the component is firing a changed event of its own when the click interaction happens. When he changes the function to accept a value, he is circumventing the issue, same as using a watched prop - but the important thing is to learn why. Either way, good answer, it works.

Comment: @Marina I agree. There are many ways to skin a cat. I just thought that this is the most direct and idiomatic way. Cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the () from the @change call as such:

```
@change="searchSubGroup"
```

If you leave the () set, then the function is getting called when the component is getting build and the "selectedgroup" is still not defined, thus calling with null

v-model works based on @change so the event is getting fired twice. The selectedGroup method is getting called BEFORE the change method that updates the v-model data. Which is why the value was the "old one".

Even though the other answer is still a correct way of avoiding the issue, it does not explain exactly why this is happening.

Heres another solution:

1. Remove your @change call from the b-form-select
2. Add a "watched" property

   `watch: {
        selectedgroup(value) {
             this.searchSubGroup();
             //OR you could remove the method and just call axios here
        })
   }`

Comment: Why does it update with a new value though? does `searchSubGroup` get called only once or each time the event is triggered as well?

Comment: @IvanS95 its getting called once at load, and then with subsequent triggers. The only time you add ( ) to a method call inside a prop is when youre going to pass a value @change="method(item)", else it gets called when rendered. Also, it would depend on how the OP's API works. Maybe it allows for null calls?

Comment: I just noticed something else, v-model actually calls @change too. So im going to edit my answer, gimme a min

Answer (score 1):

You could use `@input` instead of `@change` event because `@input="searchSubGroup"` returns the current selected item

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      selected: null,
      options: [{
          value: null,
          text: 'Please select some item'
        },
        {
          value: 'a',
          text: 'This is option a'
        },
        {
          value: 'b',
          text: 'Default Selected Option b'
        },
        {
          value: 'c',
          text: 'This is option c'
        },
        {
          value: 'd',
          text: 'This one is disabled',
          disabled: true
        },
        {
          value: 'e',
          text: 'This is option e'
        },
        {
          value: 'e',
          text: 'This is option f'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    choose() {
      console.log(this.selected)
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

  <!-- Add this after vue.js -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@latest/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="app">

    <b-form-select v-model="selected" :options="options" class="mb-3" @input="choose">
    </b-form-select>
    <div>Selected: <strong>{{ selected }}</strong></div>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```